# How to edit design in a bootstrap template?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

How do I edit the design hidden somewhere in this code? Currently this has a functioning search and I want to put an Add button next to a textbox. But I cannot even find the search in this code I'm showing below. I found this datatable template bootstrap on youtube.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Survey Settings</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
      require_once("/dao/CategoryDAO.php");
      require_once("/dao/TopicDAO.php");
      $category = new CategoryDAO();
      $topic = new TopicDAO();
      $allCategories_arr = $category->getAllCategories();
      $allTopics_arr = $topic->getAllTopicTitles();

    ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Category ID</td>
              <td>Category Name</td>
              <td >Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
              foreach($allCategories_arr as $ar) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $ar['category_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $ar['categoryname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a class='btn btn-default' href='viewsubcategory.php?catid=" . $ar['category_id'] . "' >More Info</a>";
                echo "</tr>";
              }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();    
      });
   </script>
 </body>
```

I discovered that this code was triggering the whole design. Therefore, is there anyway I can show the 'hidden' code in this script? I just want to pud an add button and a textbox next to the search.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so, basically there is a `search` function and you want add a button next to it? well, did you realize an interesing part on your js -- that [`DataTable`](https://datatables.net/)?

Comment: since you are using datatable I am assuming by textbox you are talking about the search box in the toolbar. to add to the toolbar check this out https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html

Comment: Yeah I just want to add an Add button and addbox next to it to add my data on the table. I'm not really familiar with this advanced design hence it's very hard for me to play with it

Comment: What do you want this "Add" button to do?

Comment: Insert categories in my category table, if possible I want to do the php code where I can see it so I can do it for my other datatables since this is currently displaying Categories. If I click more info it will the same design but instead show sub categories under that category therefore I need to add an add button again on that page. Same thing for the third since if I click more info on the sub category, it will show the third page which is showing the topics under that sub category. @jonmrich

Comment: this might be a possible implementation. I use this one alot to show sub categories or nested tables in my datatable.  https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: I don't think it's possible because I have a fourth table which is many questions under a topic. So it's like Category>subcategory>topics>questions under each other @BryanDellinger

Comment: almost sounds like a tree control might be what you are after https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Comment: whatever this is jstree is very new to my eyes T_T haha @BryanDellinger

Answer (score 0):

Ok not sure I totally understand your requirements but going from your original post it says an add button by the search box that allows you to insert rows into the datatable.  the solution below adds an inline form in the toolbar.  then the onclick event adds the row to the datatable.

```js
function category(id, name, action) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.action = action;
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.categories = [];
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  mymodel.categories.push(new category('1', 'Cat1', 'Post'));
  mymodel.categories.push(new category('2', 'Cat2', 'Get'));
  mymodel.categories.push(new category('3', 'Cat3', 'Put'));
  var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    data: mymodel.categories,
    columns: [{
        data: 'id'
      }, {
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'action'
      }

    ],
    dom: '<"toolbar">frtip'

  });

  $("div.toolbar").html(
    '<form class="form-inline">\
  <div class="form-group">\
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rowid" placeholder="id">\
  </div>\
  <div class="form-group">\
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">\
  </div>\
    <div class="form-group">\
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" placeholder="action">\
  </div>\
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="add" value="add"></input>\
</form>'
  );


  $('#add').click(function(event) {
    table.row.add({
      'id': $('#rowid').val(),
      'name': $('#name').val(),
      'action': $('#action').val()
    }).draw(false);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category Id</th>
      <th>Category Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```